# Mouse Over on DropDown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a multiple selecttion drop down that have values .So the issues is that the values are so long that user is not able to view them.I want to create mouse over on each value of the drop down and on mouse over i will show the user current value of the dropdown

my HTML

```
<select multiple="" style="width:190px;" class="select-box" id="hotel" name="hotel"><option value="Abassides Palace">Abassides Palace (Algiers)</option><option value="Albert Premier">Albert Premier (Algiers)</option><option value="Club Azur">Club Azur (Algiers)</option><option value="Dar Diaf Alger">Dar Diaf Alger (Algiers)</option><option value="Dar El Ikram">Dar El Ikram (Algiers)</option><option value="Dar El Ikram">Dar El Ikram (Algiers)</option><option value="El Biar">El Biar (Algiers)</option><option value="El Biar Hotel">El Biar Hotel (Algiers)</option><option value="El Marsa">El Marsa (Algiers)</option><option value="Grand Hotel Adghir">Grand Hotel Adghir (Algiers)</option><option value="Grand Hotel Adghir">Grand Hotel Adghir (Algiers)</option><option value="HILTON ALGER">HILTON ALGER (Algiers)</option><option value="Hilton Alger">Hilton Alger (Algiers)</option><option value="Hilton Alger Hotel">Hilton Alger Hotel (Algiers)</option><option value="Hotel El Aurassi">Hotel El Aurassi (Algiers)</option><option value="Hotel El-Djazair">Hotel El-Djazair (Algiers)</option><option value="Hotel El-Djazair">Hotel El-Djazair (Algiers)</option><option value="Hotel Hammamet Ain Benian">Hotel Hammamet Ain Benian (Algiers)</option><option value="Hotel Hydra">Hotel Hydra (Algiers)</option><option value="Hotel Sweet">Hotel Sweet (Algiers)</option><option value="Hydra">Hydra (Algiers)</option><option value="Ibis Alger AÃ©roport">Ibis Alger AÃ&copy;roport (Algiers)</option><option value="Majestic Annaba">Majestic Annaba (Annaba)</option><option value="Mercure Alger Aeroport">Mercure Alger Aeroport (Algiers)</option><option value="Mercure Alger Aeroport">Mercure Alger Aeroport (Algiers)</option><option value="Mimosa Palace">Mimosa Palace (Annaba)</option><option value="Mimosa Palace Annaba">Mimosa Palace Annaba (Annaba)</option><option value="Palace Appart HÃ´tel">Palace Appart HÃ´tel (Algiers)</option><option value="Rym El Djamil Annaba">Rym El Djamil Annaba (Annaba)</option><option value="Sabri Hotel">Sabri Hotel (Annaba)</option><option value="Safir Alger">Safir Alger (Algiers)</option><option value="Safir Alger">Safir Alger (Algiers)</option><option value="Safir Mazafran">Safir Mazafran (Algiers)</option><option value="Samir Hotel">Samir Hotel (Algiers)</option><option value="Sheraton Club des Pins Resort">Sheraton Club des Pins Resort (Algiers)</option><option value="Sheraton Club des Pins Resort">Sheraton Club des Pins Resort (Algiers)</option><option value="Sofitel Algiers">Sofitel Algiers (Algiers)</option><option value="Sofitel Algiers Hamma Garden">Sofitel Algiers Hamma Garden (Algiers)</option><option value="Sweet Hotel">Sweet Hotel (Algiers)</option><option value="Tulip Inn Rym el Djamil">Tulip Inn Rym el Djamil (Annaba)</option></select>
```

Please suggest me something that we can do .

Comment: use Autocomplete textbox instead of select http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @NitinChaurasia i have such requirement that i can't use auto complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a title attribute to your option.

```
<option title="Abassides Palace" value="Abassides Palace">Abassides Palace (Algiers)</option>
```

A tooltip should then show if you hover on the item. Check an example (I did the first two) in a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bekb5k2m/

Comment: Just for interest sake check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467683

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery then add a simple code like this will add the titles to all your options.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // the code is looping through all the options 
    // and setting the same value to the "title" as in "value" attribute.
    $(".select-box option").each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).attr("title", value);
    });
});
```

Here is an demo : [jsfiddle code sample](http://jsfiddle.net/qikhan/cja082c4/5/)